# custom git repo as composer package toggles between original everytime composer update is run

Tags: php, composer-php, package-managers

I have this peculiar problem with php composer. I am using `roumen/feed` package in a laravel app. But I made some custom mods to the package within a fork. Here is my fork https://github.com/foysalit/laravel-feed .

I have a `git push` to deploy setup for my laravel app configured. On each push I run `composer update` through git hook. What's weird is that, everytime I push, the feed package gets toggled. So, let's say I deploy the first time, I get my forked version installed, then I push again, it installs the original package. Then I push again, it goes back to my forked version!!

- I tried ssh-ing into the server and running composer update manually, the same happens. every time I run `composer update` it toggles the version. Here's the output:

```

```
~ composer update
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
  - Updating roumen/feed dev-master (f76ffd7 => de19954)
    Checking out de19954259dbf613acdf0aa75ad6cf4ef262084a

~ composer update
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
  - Updating roumen/feed dev-master (de19954 => f76ffd7)
    Checking out f76ffd73fc5eab35bfc6bf0029d195cde7691f89
```

```

- Here's what my composer.json looks like

`"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "v4.0.10",
        "roumen/feed": "~2.7"
    },
    "repositories": [
       {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "https://github.com/foysalit/laravel-feed.git"
       }
    ]`

I can't even figure out where to start in order to approach this issue so any pointers would be nice.